# Android crash Parcel.java SecurityException on Huawei/Xiaomi Android 9 and Android 10 In BACKGROUND

Tags: java, android, exception, crash, parcel

I have this crash on Firebase Crashlytics, but i don't know how to solve.
I don't use JobIntentService.

```
Parcel.java line 2071
android.os.Parcel.createException 
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)


Caused by java.lang.SecurityException
Caller no longer running, last stopped +4s989ms because: timed out while starting
android.os.Parcel.createException

Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.job.JobServiceContext.assertCallerLocked(JobServiceContext.java:490)
    at com.android.server.job.JobServiceContext.doDequeueWork(JobServiceContext.java:368)
    at com.android.server.job.JobServiceContext$JobCallback.dequeueWork(JobServiceContext.java:161)
    at android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub.onTransact(IJobCallback.java:83)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this issue tracker to see if we have any updates https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293

I have the same issue at my company, but we believe is coming from a 3rd party library since we don't use any `IntentService`.

If you have control over a `IntentService`, this post might help you https://medium.com/@eng.zak/workaround-to-solve-securityexception-caused-by-jobintentservice-1f4b0e688a26